# Error when accessing .xlsb file using xlwings

Tags: python-3.x, excel, xlwings, xlsb

I am building a programme to automate a process in Excel using xlwings.

The files I have to access include .xlsx, .xlsb and .xlsm formats

I have the following command:

```
wb = xw.Book(r"some_directory\file1.xlsx")
```

which runs fine.

But when I run any of the next two commands:

```
wb = xw.Book(r"some_directory\file2.xlsb")
```

I get the following error:

> Input In [10], in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 wb = xw.Book(r"some_directory\file2.xlsb")
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py:682, in
> Book.**init**(self, fullname, update_links, read_only, format,
> password, write_res_password, ignore_read_only_recommended, origin,
> delimiter, editable, notify, converter, add_to_mru, local,
> corrupt_load, impl)
> 680     if not app:
> 681         app = App(add_book=False)
> --> 682     impl = app.books.open(fullname, update_links, read_only, format, password, write_res_password,
> 683                           ignore_read_only_recommended, origin, delimiter, editable, notify, converter,
> 684                           add_to_mru, local, corrupt_load).impl
> 685 elif len(candidates) > 1:
> 686     raise Exception("Workbook '%s' is open in more than one Excel instance." % fullname)
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py:4278, in
> Books.open(self, fullname, update_links, read_only, format, password,
> write_res_password, ignore_read_only_recommended, origin, delimiter,
> editable, notify, converter, add_to_mru, local, corrupt_load)    4276
> try:    4277     impl = self.impl(name)
> -> 4278     if not os.path.samefile(impl.fullname, fullname):    4279         raise ValueError(    4280             "Cannot open two workbooks named
> '%s', even if they are saved in different locations." % name    4281
> )    4282 except KeyError:
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py:100, in samefile(f1, f2)
> 94 def samefile(f1, f2):
> 95     """Test whether two pathnames reference the same actual file or directory
> 96
> 97     This is determined by the device number and i-node number and
> 98     raises an exception if an os.stat() call on either pathname fails.
> 99     """
> --> 100     s1 = os.stat(f1)
> 101     s2 = os.stat(f2)
> 102     return samestat(s1, s2)
>
> OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label
> syntax is incorrect: 'some_directory\file2.xlsb'

How do I access file2.xlsb using xlwings?

Comment: @BigBen, the commands works only with the .xlsx file. When I tried using the .xlsb file or even the .xlsm file, I get this error

Comment: I just edited my question and included the full stack trace

Comment: Is this workbook saved in a OneDrive location?

Comment: Yes it is, along with the other files I have mentioned.

Comment: I read an `.xlsb` just fine from a local directory, and suspect that something with your OneDrive is causing this error.

Comment: The error suggests that you are trying to open a workbook that has the same name as a workbook that is already open: `"Cannot open two workbooks named '%s', even if they are saved in different locations."`

Comment: @Rawson I was only opening one file then but still faced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may have been to do with the way that OneDrive was set up in the environment I was working in. I managed to open the file in a server that was outside this environment.